# Can I fly to a class D airport with an NPPL?

Tags: air-traffic-control, airspace, visual-flight-rules, caa-uk-regulations

I wish to fly into Bristol (EGGD) in a Microlight.

I can see they have a VFR approach procedure [here](https://www.vatsim.uk/airports/EGGD). Can I do this? If so, what are the prerequisites? Assuming filing a flight plan is one of them.

Comment: Have you checked the landing/handling fee at Bristol? I suspect it will put you off!

Comment: @Jamiec what is it?

Comment: 3rd May 2023 comment on sky demon.  Someone quoted £299 for landing and 30 mins parking.  That's excluding handling. No idea if it's genuine,  but it wouldn't surprise me.

Comment: @Jamiec here are the fees... it's a minefield, no idea how to calculate the total haha https://www.bristolairport.co.uk/media/4jsdumh1/fees-and-charges-1-april-2022.pdf

Comment: Maybe there is a cheaper airport I can go to? I just want to practice landing somewhere large and talking on the real radio :)

Comment: I also found that,  I also can't make head nor tails. Phone atc if you want the answer.  In answer to your other comment - Southend.  Much more ga friendly.  Great large airport. Expensive,  but nothing like Bristol. In the region of £30-50

Answer (score 5, accepted):

VATSIM is not a good place to look for information on real-world flying. The authoritative source for what you're looking at is the [UK AIP](https://www.aurora.nats.co.uk/htmlAIP/Publications/2023-05-18-AIRAC/html/index-en-GB.html). Here's the [Control area chart for Bristol](https://www.aurora.nats.co.uk/htmlAIP/Publications/2023-05-18-AIRAC/html/index-en-GB.html). The textual information states

> VFR and Special VFR aircraft will usually be instructed to route via one of the Visual Reference Points (paragraph 5 refers), not above altitude 2000 FT (aerodrome QNH).

Further info also states

> Due to restricted GA parking, operators of inbound GA flights must notify handling agents with expected ETA and duration of stay. Handling mandatory

That should give you a pretty strong indication that

- GA is not *particularly* welcome
- It's going to cost you!

There is nothing (except ATC clearance obviously) stopping you from flying into controlled airspace in a microlight with an NPPL. There is no pre-requisite to file a flight plan, as far as I'm aware.